# Power method for calculating dominant eigenvalue and eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to know if there are any counter example when the method does not work when there is a dominant eigenvalue.

Let $\lambda_1$ be the dominant eigenvalue of some matrix $M$.
From the wording on Wikipedia, whilst this method always work when eigenvalues have distinct magnitudes, but may fail if there exists $\lambda_i$, $\lambda_j$ such that $|\lambda_i|=|\lambda_j|$ even though $i\neq 1\neq j$. Does anyone have a solid example of this （or have I misunderstood)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the matrix is diagonalizable and there is a dominant eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ in the sense that $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_i|$ for all $i \neq 1$, then the method works, regardless of the character of the other eigenvalues. One can drop the diagonalizability assumption with some additional work.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration but this suggests the sequence of vectors may not converge?

Comment: @Lost1 The only condition I haven't mentioned here is that the initial vector must have a component in the direction of the dominant eigenvector. This hypothesis is not any difficulty in practice, because nearly the entire space has this property, so one can choose a vector uniformly at random from the unit cube, and convergence will occur with probability 1.

Comment: If the dominant eigenvector $v$, You mean as long as we pick an initial vector $u_0$. As long as $v.u_0 \neq 0$, this is convergent?

Comment: @Lost1 Correct.

Comment: through a more careful reading of the theorem of the wikipedia page, it seems like the problem can only occurs if the matrix is complex, since for a real matrix, the dominant eigenvalue cannot be complex. The non convergence comes from the fact different subsequence converge to different eigenvectors.

Comment: @Lost1 There is still no problem in the complex situation provided there is a dominant eigenvalue in the sense of modulus.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will read it through again.